# How can I enforce 16-byte alignment for certain members of a class?

Tags: c++, sse, simd, memory-alignment, class-members

Let's say I have something like:

```
class C
{
private:
    __m128i m0;
    __m128i m1;
    __m128i cm0;

    int s0;

...

}
```

This can cause problems because m0, m1, and cm0 are not guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned, allowing for alignment-related access violations.  If I absolutely wanted to have private simd class members whose alignment I could guarantee, how ought I do that?

Edit: specifically in my case, I'm using an std::vector of a class that has __m128i members (in addition to 32 and 64 bit integers.  Is it possible to force 16-byte alignment of my class members within an std::vector?

Comment: Class members are guaranteed to have their alignment requirements satisfied in local or static variables, and in local or static arrays.  If you dynamically allocate memory, you can run into problems.  I'm guessing you're trying to use a `std::vector<C>` or similar?  If so, say so.

Comment: You are correct, I am trying to use a vector of a class like this one.  Any recommendations?

Comment: You cannot "align members" without also aligning the entire class to at leas the same value. Otherwise you could just displace the whole object by the class's permitted alignment and break the member alignment. (The class layout is of course fixed and not decided per object.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround that I found to solve my own issues.

What I did was twofold:

Initially, I'd been working with something like:

```
std::vector<C> myVector(mySize);
```

I elected to do instead:

```
C* myVector = _aligned_malloc(sizeof(C) * mySize, 16);
```

Secondly, I added some variable padding to class C such that it's size in bytes would be a multiple of 16.  I'm not keen on the wasted space that entails, so I may rework things in the future (perhaps one block of memory for the simd variables and a separate block for the others).

Comment: Let the compiler pad it for you.  You can see that in action by putting an `int size = sizeof(C)` in your code and look at the asm output, [like this on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/p1RckS) for example.  (Note that Godbolt targets the System V ABI, not the Windows ABI, and they might not always agree on struct layout, but they will always pad to a multiple of the required alignment so that all elements of an array have the required alignment.)

Comment: But yes, if you don't need the features of `std::vector`, it can be easier to avoid it than to pass a custom allocator that allocates aligned storage.  IDK why `std::vector` doesn't use an allocator that satisfies alignment requirements by default. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind wasting a bit of RAM, you can do an aligned_holder wrapper class that will guarantee that the object it holds will be aligned to whatever alignment boundary you specify.  (Note that the amount of wasted RAM is equal to the specified alignment boundary)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <new>

// Makes sure that its held object is always aligned to the specified alignment-value,
// at the cost of using up some extra RAM.
template<class T, int AlignTo=16> class aligned_holder
{
public:
   aligned_holder()
   {
      new (getAlignedPointer()) T();
   }

   ~aligned_holder()
   {
      getAlignedObject().~T();
   }

   T & getAlignedObject() {return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(getAlignedPointer());}
   const T & getAlignedObjectConst() const {return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(getAlignedPointerConst());}

private:
   char * getAlignedPointer()
   {
      const ptrdiff_t offset = intptr_t(_buf)%AlignTo;
      return &_buf[(intptr_t)(AlignTo-offset)];
   }

   const char * getAlignedPointerConst() const
   {
      const ptrdiff_t offset = intptr_t(_buf)%AlignTo;
      return &_buf[(intptr_t)(AlignTo-offset)];
   }

   char _buf[AlignTo+sizeof(T)];
};
```

... and a unit test, to (hopefully) verify that I didn't mess up the example:

```
class IWannaBeAligned
{
public:
   IWannaBeAligned()
   {
      const intptr_t iThis = (intptr_t)(this);
      if ((iThis % 16) != 0) printf("Error!  object %p is not 16-byte aligned!  (offset=%ld)\n", this, iThis%16);
                        else printf("Good, object %p is 16-byte aligned.\n", this);
   }

   ~IWannaBeAligned()
   {
      printf("Deleting object %p\n", this);
   }

   char buf[32];  // just to give it a more realistic object size than one byte
};

int main()
{
   {
      printf("First, let's try it without the aligned_holder:\n");
      IWannaBeAligned notAligned;
   }

   printf("\n");

   {
      printf("Now, we'll try it with the aligned_holder:\n");
      aligned_holder<IWannaBeAligned> isAligned;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can use [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas). As the example on that page shows, your code can be writen like this:

```
class alignas(16) C
{
private:
    __m128i m0;
    __m128i m1;
    __m128i cm0;

    int s0;

...

}
```

Comment: That's redundant, `__m128i` is already a 16-byte aligned type.  The OP's actual problem is trying to use the class with `std::vector`, i.e. an allocator that doesn't respect `alignof(C)`.  Anything that does respect `alignof(C)` will already work without extra `alignas`.